# How to separate The Day, Month and Year attributes using SQL _Open query in salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, date, sql, split

I have creating TestDE Data extension using these attributes like SubscriberKey, AccountID, EventDate, Date, Month, Year attributes. And Created with same attributes using Target Data extension. Now my requirement is how to write a SQL query on '_Open' for Split date, Month and Year. Can anybody help on this.

### See below image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Datepart()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp) function. In your case it would be

```
select 
Datepart(year, EventDate) as Year, 
Datepart(month, EventDate) as Month ... 

from _Open
```

Comment: Thanks for giving fast reply!! , And also Here month showing number format,I need to show month in text format like January, February like that